# Graph API returns email as null partially

Tags: email, facebook-graph-api

We are developing a Facebook-App that retrieves the user's data via Graph API. We are suffering an odd situation where the emails of users are sometimes (ca. 25%) delivered by Facebook as null or empty values. We assume that the logging with phone-number causes this problem. But, anyways each user must have an email address, doesnt he?

For any hint or idea, we thank you all!

Comment: i found this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/482815835078469/

Answer (score 1):

This is a known Facebook bug. For more information see [this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298946933534016/) and [this other](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/429653750464521/) bug report.